# How do I get the option (during login) to select Unity back?

Tags: gdm

When I turn my computer on a screen comes up asking me for a password. This is not the typical Ubuntu log in screen, but it looks like the Gnome log in.

[image]

Usually this gives me a choice of what to log in to: Unity, Gnome, Gnome no effects, etc.

This time around I have no choice, it just takes me into the current version of Gnome (don't know to call this the shell or Gnome 3).

Everything works fine, but the normal Unity session is missing, as are the other Gnome options.

How do I get the option to select Unity back?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot somewhere?

Comment: A screen shot of the log in prompt?

Comment: Yes, the "not typical Ubuntu log in screen", we need to figure that out first.

Comment: https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSnS6aMajMhbjEmgXSfq6xiRvH-hMhd-FgaCJB7QUMHD6rbwx0f

This is characteristic of the screen I am currently getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `lightdm` is the default in ubuntu, a different login screen means you installed some other display manager. It seems that you are currently using `gdm`, so to revert back just input this line in the terminal:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm`

and choose `lightdm` as the default display manager.

Comment: This looks like it will restore the login, but will it bring back the Ubuntu/Unity option?

Comment: If you have Unity installed (which I assume you have), it will.

Comment: Bingo. Problem solved. Thank you to everyone for your help.